# Android Doze drops Wifi regardless of optimalization settings

Tags: lg-g3, doze-mode

My LG G3 with Android 6.0 uses the built in Doze mode to save some battery.

At the first setup, I set applications to ignore Doze mode (like chat apps, Gmail, Viber etc.). I also set the "app" called Wifi to make my Wifi enabled while in Doze mode. They worked okay, I get my messages even if my phone is in Doze mode.

After 1 year of usage, when I unlock my phone, I can see that my phone is switching from *mobile data* to *Wifi* and my data package is being used up by the aforementioned disabled programs.

Why? And how can I make my phone to use Wifi permanently? What changed after 1 year?

Comment: It is not related to Doze AFAIK.. More like your WiFi is weak so it is switching over to data. Use this to measure WiFi strength when it happens and compare with known good WiFi [WiFi Analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)

Comment: This is enabled under developer options> > mobile data always active

Comment: @beeshyams I keep my phone 15 cm away from the router and the signal quality is excellent. When I unlock my phone and return from Doze, it immediately switches to Wifi - like it has just woken up.

Comment: I see. Then it's a different issue. Let's wait for others to pitch in

Comment: It seems like a bug in Doze itself - it's not expecting to do anything in that state, so needing to keep connected is making it forget how to connect. A workaround could be putting your phone in airplane mode, and then turning on the WiFi (yes, you can do that while in airplane mode)

Comment: @DanB: good idea. Or as a workaround, use automation app (like Macrodroid) to disable data when WiFi connected. I use that trick to prevent data being on accidentally. There may be other apps on play store for this

Comment: @beeshyams Also a good idea :)

Comment: It can be configured to act on unlocking screen, if OP needs it as an interim solution

Comment: Thanks for the tips, guys, but as you mentioned it, they are _workarounds_ and not based on system settings. I hope it will be fixed by Google or LG ports 6.x version to this phone.